# Why is the parent process not executing at all?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Following is the program for shared memory implementation where the parent and the child processes are to use the shared memory for printing the next alphabet to that given by the parent.

There is a shared memory and both the processes are attaching to it to obtain the required result. In my code, the parent process does not execute at all.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
   int smid;
   pid_t x;
   char *sm;
   smid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,(size_t)sizeof(char),IPC_CREAT);
   x=fork();
   if(x>0)
    {

     sm=(char *)shmat(smid,NULL,0);
     sprintf(sm,"%s",argv[1]);
     printf("Parent wrote:\n");
     puts(sm);
     sleep(4);
     printf("Parent got:\n");
     puts(sm);
     shmdt(sm);
     shmctl(smid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
      }
     else if(x==0)
     {
      sleep(2);
 sm=(char *)shmat(smid,NULL,0);
 printf("Child read:\n");
 puts(sm);
 sm[0]++;
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Conclusory statements are not helpful. You need to tell us what output you expected and what output you got. Or, at a minimum, *how* you reached the conclusion that the parent does not execute.

Comment: The control doesn't enter the block for the parent process. "parent wrote" or "parent got" is not being outputted at all. Rather it says "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Again, that's a conclusion. What makes you think that? What evidence do you have for that conclusion? What did you expect? What did you observe?

Comment: Well all I can say now is use gdb ; crash here "sprintf(sm,"%s",argv[1]);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the cause for this program

```
smid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,(size_t)sizeof(char),IPC_CREAT);
```

src is allocated single byte but what follows is bizzare,

```
    char *src=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(src,argv[0]); // argv[0] is more than 1 
    sm=(char *)shmat(smid,NULL,0);
    sprintf(sm,"%s",src); // it has NULL at the end
```

loosely fixed program..

```
    int smid;
    pid_t x;
    char *sm;
    smid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,(size_t)120*sizeof(char),IPC_CREAT|0666); // permissions and size are important
    perror("smid ");
    x=fork();
    if(x>0)
    {
            char *src=(char *)malloc(120*sizeof(char)); // size is the key here
            sm=(char *)shmat(smid,NULL,0);
            perror("shmat" );
            strcpy(src,argv[0]);
            sprintf(sm,"%s",src);
            printf("Parent wrote:\n");
            puts(sm);
            sleep(4);
            printf("Parent got:\n");
            puts(sm);
            shmdt(sm);
            shmctl(smid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
    }
    else if(x==0)
    {
            sleep(2);
            sm=(char *)shmat(smid,NULL,0);
            printf("Child read:\n");
            puts(sm);
            sm[0]++;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed my code. Now it's argv[1] and I'm not using src anymore. I'm passing argv[1] directly in sprintf instead of src.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have *undefined behavior* in the program. You allocate memory for a single character, and then use `strcpy` which will most likely copy *more* than one character (and even if it copies one character, you have to remember it also copies the string terminator so actually two characters are copied).

Undefined behavior is often a leading cause for crashes, which is probably what happens in your code.